# MySQL order by headache

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with Firstnames and Lastname, an I'd like to check if there are no swapped data.

**Table**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  0 |  Raphael  |  Thomas  |
|  1 |   Robert  | Vincent  |
|  2 | Philippe  |  Michel  |
|  3 |  Vincent  |  Robert  |
|  4 |   Thomas  | Raphael  |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to group the result and then highlight any couples

**Expected result**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  0 |  Raphael  |  Thomas  |
|  4 |   Thomas  | Raphael  |
|  1 |   Robert  | Vincent  |
|  3 |  Vincent  |  Robert  |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

This works when the number of characters of fisrtname+lastname is different but not when the sum is the same

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.lastname, t1.firstname
FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t2.lastname = t1.firstname AND t2.firstname = t1.lastname
ORDER BY length(t1.lastname)+length(t1.firstname)
```

I have also tried to convert to HEX and sum the HEX results but got a "DOUBLE value is out of range" error.

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `LEAST`/`GREATEST` trick here:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    firstname,
    lastname
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Id <> t1.Id AND 
              t2.lastname = t1.firstname AND t2.firstname = t1.lastname)
ORDER BY
    LEAST(firstname, lastname),
    GREATEST(firstname, lastname);
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Great !!! Thanks for the tip Tim, I ignored LEAST / GREATEST functions

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to UNION the result by searching the lastName in first query matching the firstName column and searching the firstName in second query matching the lastName column?

```
select id,firstname,lastname from table WHERE firstname IN(select lastName from table)
UNION
select id,firstname,lastname from table WHERE lastname IN(select firstname from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an **INNER JOIN** works great for this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.firstname, t1.lastname FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.lastname = t1.firstname AND t2.firstname = t1.lastname
GROUP BY t1.firstname, t1.lastname
ORDER BY t1.firstname, t1.lastname
```

**Expected output:**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  0 |  Raphael  |  Thomas  |
|  1 |   Robert  | Vincent  |
|  4 |   Thomas  | Raphael  |
|  3 |  Vincent  |  Robert  |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Inner joins only show results that appear on both sides of the join, never the orphans.

The **GROUP BY** is useful if wanting to keep it to unique value combinations, entirely **optional** if you dont allow non-reverse duplicates (so if cant insert two "Thomas, Raphael" in that order, then no need for it)

- [Mysql INNER JOIN](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-join) (https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-join)

> The MySQL INNER JOIN is used to return all rows from multiple tables
>   where the join condition is satisfied. It is the most common type of
>   join.

- [Mysql GROUP BY](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-group-by) (https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-group-by)

> The MYSQL GROUP BY Clause is used to collect data from multiple
>   records and group the result by one or more column. It is generally
>   used in a SELECT statement.

Keeps it short and sweet :)